# How to restart a PM2 process with process name instead of process id?

Tags: node.js, pm2

When we are running multiple node services in a single machine, its becoming hard to restart one service with id as id is a sequence number allocated in order by PM2. So instead using the id is it possible to restart the process using process name?

I start my services with the service name using following command:

```
pm2 start index.js --name my-service-name
```

I want to restart them using the name 'my-service-name' so that I can automate it using a script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/process-management/):

```
pm2 start web.js --name "web-interface"
pm2 restart web-interface
```

Comment: Thank you, I was referring their Quick Start page http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#cheat-sheet and this information is missing there.